# Create a Column from int[] or List<Integer>

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to create a Column (that I will add to a `DataSet<Row>`) from an `int[]` or `List<Integer>` in Java and [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/).

The values I am using are distinct (because the closest answer I have found is creating a column using the same `value funtions.lit(val)`).

```
public Dataset<Row> addColumn(String colName, int value ,int[] values){
        Dataset<Row> ds = data.withColumn(colName, functions.lit(value));
        return ds;
}
```

this gives a column with the same value.

How create a Column using an `int[]` or `List<Integer>`?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your trial code

Comment: your question is really so ambiguous, please give more information about your main problem not the problems you are face with on the way to solve it.

Comment: The problem is: how to create a Column using an array of int or a list of Integer.